# How to safely set/clear only some bits of SCB->SHCSR on ARM Cortex-M processors?

Tags: arm, interrupts, assembly

On p. 265 of the third edition of Joseph Yiu's *The Definitive Guide to Arm Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M4 Processors*, there is some discussion about the "system handler control and state register" (`SCB->SHCSR`) which is typically "used by application code only for enabling configurable fault handlers".

Now this register contains three set of bits: one set for enabling/disabling handlers, another set that tracks which faults are pended, and another set which tracks which are active. All three sets are R/W, and author warns:

> Be cautious when writing to this register; make sure that the active status bits of system exceptions are not changed accidentally. For example, to enable the Bus Fault Exception, you should use a read-modify-write operation:
>
> ```
> SCB->SHCSR |= 2<<17; // Enable Bus Fault exception
> ```
>
> Otherwise, if an activated system exception has its active state cleared by accident, a fault exception will be generated when the system exception handler generates an exception exit.

But I fail to see how the example code prevents accidental modification of unintended bits. I do not see `|=` meaning anything special as far as the "idiom recognition" table later in the book goes, and the lead-up itself calls this a [read-modify-write](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/k/writing-arm-assembly-language/the-read-modify-write-operation) operation which I understand to be [three **separate**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549952/why-is-read-modify-write-necessary-for-registers-on-embedded-systems) (and non-[exclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894059/atomic-operations-in-arm)!) instructions. When I compiled that line of code using TI's ARM toolchain, the sequence indeed is:

```
LDR       A2, $C$CON4           ; (this just loads the register's address)
LDR       A1, [A2, #0]
ORR       A1, A1, #262144
STR       A1, [A2, #0]
```

So what happens if right after the `LDR A1, [A2, #0]` some interrupt happens (e.g. SysTick fires) and that ends up pending one of the faults tracked in this very register? When the `STR A1, [A2, #0]` happens won't it overwrite that pending bit with stale state?

Wouldn't it be necessary to actually `__disable_fault_irq()` before modifying this register and then [at least in a multi-processor setting] use an exclusive load/store sequence to safely write this? The author has taken pains to point out the risks of messing with other status bits in this register but only shows a normal/routine (non-atomic) example of modifying the register.